# VB6 application oracle 12 64bit connection

Tags: oracle, vb6, 64-bit

We have a number of applications written in VB6 (not .NET) that have been running for almost 20 years.
These applications are running on Windows 2007 64bit servers and connecting to Oracle-11 with a 32bit client.
The connection string contains "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle"
So far, so good.

The problem is that we need to convert, for reasons that go beyond the scope of this thread) to Oracle-12 64bit.
After having installed the Oracle 12-client (and disinstalled the Oracle-11 client), we get the following error when trying to open the connection:
"Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."

I'm sure we did install the client and am therefore afraid that VB6 cannot connect to Oracle using the 64bit client.

Apparently easy solutions are unfortunately out of the question:
- Convert to .NET or whatsoever and compile under 64 bit
- Keep the 32bit oracle client.

Any idea how to risolve this?

Comment: Are you using DAO or ADO datasets/recordsets?

Comment: We're using ADO

Comment: Are you using ODBC connections as well?

Comment: Not using ODBC so far. Any idea how to use that in VB6?

Comment: Without converting the whole set, could you afford to write only a "small" 32 .net dll only for the connection with Oracle DB ? [Seems possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813384/connect-to-oracle-database-without-client-installation-on-net) to talk with the database wihout a client.

Comment: You **must** compile your VB6 application as "x64" resp. "AnyCPU". Otherwise it will not load the 64 bit Oracle Client.

Comment: Follow this instruction to install 32 bit and 64 bit Oracle Client (and according OLEDB drivers) at the same time on one machine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: @wernfried-domscheit There is no 64 bit compiler so you can't compile as x64 and AnyCPU is an option presented in visual studio, not the VB6 ide.

Answer (score 4):

## OLE-DB

Good news and bad; because Visual Basic 6.0 is a 32 bit program with no 64 bit compiler, the `32 bit Oracle Data Access Components` software must be installed, even if the database itself is running on a 64 bit server in a 64 bit Oracle Database install, specifically you need the `32 bit Oracle Provider for OLE DB` rather than the whole client.

The driver can be found here (Download the ODAC XCopy version):
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html

The following thread describes your exact problem and instructions on fixing it:
https://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/connecting-to-an-oracle-database-with-visual-basic-6-0-on-windows-8-64-bit/

## ODBC drivers

Another way to connect is to use ODBC drivers instead, there are pros and cons to each method so google to find them.

First you'll need to install the `SQORA32 ODBC driver` which comes with the 64 bit client or with the ODAC linked above.

Next, you'll need to create an ODBC connection, instructions can be found here:
https://tensix.com/2012/06/setting-up-an-oracle-odbc-driver-and-data-source/

Finally you need to change your connections strings in VB6 to use the newly created ODBC connections. Something along the lines of the following should work nicely (obviously nameOfDatabase is the name given to your odbc connection):

```
Provider=MSDASQL;Dsn=nameOfDatabase;Uid=usernameHere;Pwd=passwordHere
```

Be careful when you set up your DSN, make sure you use the 32 bit ODBC connection manager which can be found in the following location:

```
c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

The same program can be found in the `system32` folder but that's the 64 bit version....not confusing at all!

Comment: I tried the solution as stated in the hoopercharles site but it doesn't fix my problem. We cannot have the 32- and 64-bit client contemporarily (we need the 64bit for other purposes as well). I'm working on the ODBC thread. I'll be back (it's midnight over here)

Comment: I created an ODBC DSN that uses the driver SQORA32.DLL (that comes despite its name, with the 64bit client). The connection string "Provider=MSDASQL;Dsn=TestOracle;Uid=hello;Pwd=there". It seems to work. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes it does, we use ODBC connections rather than oledb because we have dao and sql server. I'll post the relevant ODBC stuff up for future reference

Comment: Actually, it does because VB6 does not have a 64 bit compiler

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. When running "wscript", the ODBC connection works. Within our application we get the error: "[Mircosoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and the Application". The very same thing happens when launching the 32-bit "c:\windows\SysWOW64\wscript"

Comment: @RobertKock Have you set up a dsn using the 32 bit driver? c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe. Answer updated to show this

Comment: When launching "c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe" I don't see the the driver "Oracle in OraClient12Home1" that uses SQORA32.DLL. Any idea how to install that one in the 32bit ODBC configurator? It does show "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" that uses MSORCL32.DLL but it complains that the client components were not found.

Comment: That suggests that the 32 bit version oracle driver hasn't been properly installed or is in a different location

Comment: In your question you stated that your uninstalled the 32-bit Oracle 11 Client. Of course, then the 32 bit ODBC driver does not work. You have to install a 32 bit Oracle client.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of: There's no way to make VB6 connect to oracle with only a 64bit client installed.

Answer (score 0):

(If you can't follow the solution of twoleggedhorse, which is way better.)

You can write a *small* DLL in .NET 32bit, and make it COM visible so it will be usable by your 32 bits application.

I said in my comment that it seems to be possible in .NET to talk with the DB [without an installed client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813384/connect-to-oracle-database-without-client-installation-on-net).

To make it through the least painful, you can write it ADO-like (ie a class to replace RecordSet, another for Connection, and so on). Then add it as a reference to your projects and perform a search/replace.

Comment: A bit overkill I would say.

Comment: As I said, _only_ if an ODBC connection isn't possible. It's an intermediate solution, not out-of-the-box, but not too expensive at all.